# How to add a new DSL line

Tags: networking, adsl, wiring

I have a DSL connection coming into my kitchen. I don't want my router and modem on the kitchen counter. What is the best way to add a second connection? Can I simply add a second twisted pair to the DSL box and run the line to my basement?

[image: outside DSL box]

Comment: You can loose signal strength to re-run the cable, as with DSL you got a max distance to respect (your house to the phone compagny) (+- 2km usually), but usually you can do it to re-run. ServerFault is not suited for that question on the other side. diy.stackexchange.com/ is maybe the correct place for the question.

Comment: Do you have any other ports in your home that would be RJ-45? I'm wondering if you only have one home run ran from your kitchen and others might be daisy chained. Otherwise you'd have to add a second line and run it from the box in the picture, to your basement.

Comment: *"I have a DSL connection coming into my kitchen"* -- Is this a specifically designated *"DSL"* jack, or are you just using this phone jack for that purpose?  If you do not have a whole-house ADSL filter (i.e. each phone still requires its own inline ADSL filter), then you can move the modem to *any* RJ11 phone jack in the house.

Answer (score 0):

Make a home run for the modem back to the Telco demarc (terminating box). The cable is pretty much your choice, cat-3 will work fine depending on the type of DSL.

Even though it would be using one out of four pairs. I would personally just run cat-5/cat-5e to the demarc. Maybe you can reuse the cable when you are ready to upgrade your ISP later.

BTW, between CAT-3, CAT-5/5E AND CAT-6 there will be absolutely no difference in the connection speed you receive.

Regards,

Answer (score -3):

**Can I simply add a second twisted pair to the DSL box and run the line to my basement?** Yes!

Might sound like overkill, but if you run CAT6 SFTP you will get very good EMF shielding which can help protect against interference from power, gadgets, wifi signal etc, where the cable is travelling through the house. Can help you get a higher synch speed.

Comment: Category-6 cable for this is really a waste of money. Telcos use Category-3 cable, and at the frequencies involved, Category-6 cable does nothing for you that the Category-3 cable doesn't. In fact, you can cause problems by mixing different cable categories on a signal. and all components of a cable system must match to actually gain a category rating. The termination point is obviously not Category-6, and the line coming in from the telco is Category-3.

Comment: Notice I said not just CAT6 but SFTP - shielded - I'm sure that in theory you are right, but in practice, if you have your cable running past an EMF source in your house then the shielding will protect it. Could be a difference of 10-20mbits/sec synch speed depending on the interference.

Comment: Shielding must be end-to-end on the cable, and it must be grounded. The telco will not have that. Also, at the frequencies used. it is pointless.

Comment: Maybe it is a coincidence, I can't explain it, but I found it makes a difference.

Comment: @ron maupin. This clearly IS NOT cat-3 coming from the Telco side. It's four pair and twisted. ISP's and CLECs here are installing CAT-5 UTP to the modem on new/upgraded connections past 10Mbps. But I agree, telling someone to install CAT-6 shielded & foiled is rediculous.

Comment: The shielding can also harm the signal... CAT5 is plenty for DSL.